# Ubuntu 14.04 can't connect A2DP

Tags: sound, bluetooth, a2dp

I can't connect A2DP audio sink to my laptop.
Blueman says `Stream setup failed` while connecting to `Audio sink`.

I tried a few solutions I found on the internet but I still can't hear a sound from my headset.

Is there any real good documentation on how `bluetootk` (does not) work on Ubuntu? I'm quite lost between `pavucontrol`, `pactl`, `hcitool`, `hciconfig`, `blueman`, `bluez`...

#### pactl list modules | grep discover

```
Argument: device_id="0" name="pci-0000_00_1b.0" card_name="alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0" namereg_fail=false tsched=yes fixed_latency_range=no ignore_dB=no deferred_volume=yes use_ucm=yes card_properties="module-udev-detect.discovered=1"
```

#### lsusb

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 05a9:7670 OmniVision Technologies, Inc. OV7670 Webcam
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 1131:1001 Integrated System Solution Corp. KY-BT100 Bluetooth Adapter
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Comment: Can you open terminal and enter `pactl list modules | grep discover` and then `lsusb` and add the results to your question

Answer (score 1):

You likely need to load this `sudo pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover` then delete the pairing and then pair again and you should then be able to change the audio output setting to your headset

Comment: It works. pavucontrol showing "headphones" as output but there is no sound. I use VLC to play a song and changing output to "Speakers" works very well.

Comment: This worked, after executing the command I could connect to my JBL Go via A2DP sink. I also had to tweak the alsa output settings so the app that produces the sound uses the JBL Go device. All of this can be done using the UI though.

Comment: My bluetooth headset works after "sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-module-bluetooth", running pactl command above and fooling around in sound settings.

Answer (score 1):

To not require the pactl call, you can download and install the blueman Debian package from utopic: http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic/blueman

Comment: I already use it to connect the headset. By loading module-bluetooth-discover, I can connect the headset with blueman but there is no sound on the headset...